# How to set the font of a PdfFormField in iText?

Tags: .net, itext

How do you set the font for a field using iText when created as follows:

```
PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader("C:\\foo.pdf");
FileStream outs = new FileStream("C:\\bar.pdf", FileMode.Create, 
                  FileAccess.Write);
PdfStamper stamps = new PdfStamper(pdf, outs);
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateTextField(stamps.Writer, 
                     false, false, 50);
field.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(50, 400, 500, 600),
      PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
field.FieldName = "my_field";
stamps.AddAnnotation(field, 1);
stamps.Close();
```

I already have a ref to a BaseFont and would like to set the field font so that when I open Acrobat and inspect the form fields the appearance property will show this font.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the code of the TextField class, more specifically at the getTextField() method. You'll see that the font is defined in the default appearance (DA). Many things are going on in that method. The appearance is created, a BaseFont is added.

Either you'll have to write your own implementation of what is done in the TextField class, or you'll have to switch to using the TextField class.

Is there a specific reason why you're avoiding TextField?

Comment: Yes.  I created a text field and set the font but when I go to Acrobat

Comment: Sorry I did get the font set in the field when I look in Acrobat but I want it to say Arial instead of SEBJIU+ArialMT

Comment: This the code I used:             BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            field.FontSize = 12;
            field.Font = arial;

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional question:

I did get the font set in the field when I look in Acrobat but I want it to say Arial instead of SEBJIU+ArialMT

This the code I used: BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

I have two remarks for you:

1. ArialMT is the name of the font that is stored in the file arial.ttf. If you want the font to appear with a different name, you need to use the method setPostscriptFontName() in the BaseFont class. It's possible, but I would advise against it, as it's misleading.
2. The SEBJIU+ prefix means that only a subset of the font is used. If you use setSubset(false) the prefix will disappear.

I see that you're not embedding the font, but the prefix tells me you are embedding a subset. Maybe there's something else at play. In some cases, the embedded parameter is ignored. This is documented. For instance Standard Type 1 fonts are never embedded (even if you use BaseFont.EMBEDDED); fonts using encoding IDENTITY-H or IDENTITY-V are always embedded.

Comment: The prefix does not appear when BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
  What confuses me is when I create a text field using acrobat and set the font to Arial it does not show up as an embedded font until I enter text into the field.  When I create a text field using iText and set the font to Arial it shows up as ArialMT and it shows up as embedded. (I do understand that Arial and ArialMT are the same).    Is there any reason why Acrobat does this?

Comment: If you pick a font for a field, it's better to embed it, so that the text shows up OK when somebody enters text on a machine that doesn't know the font. As for the difference between Arial and ArialMT: maybe Acrobat and iText are indeed using a different font program. You are using the one in C:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf, but often Acrobat uses its own font packs. Go to c:/Program Files/Adobe and look for .ttf and .otf files. Maybe there's an Arial there... Or maybe Acrobat uses the 'family name' of the font. We choose the PostScript name because that's usually the most accurate name.

Comment: Thanks again for your help as I am now able to handle the fonts.  What I would really like to do is use the embedded font found by:

Comment: ArrayList fonts = BaseFont.GetDocumentFonts(myReader);
            BaseFont[] baseFonts = new BaseFont[fonts.Count];
            string[] fn = new string[fonts.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < fonts.Count; i++)
            {
                Object[] obj = (Object[])fonts[i];
                baseFonts[i] = BaseFont.CreateFont((PRIndirectReference)(obj[1]));
                fn[i] = baseFonts[i].PostscriptFontName.ToString();
            }
and then set the field.Font to one of the fonts found.  When I display the resulting pdf in acrobat any entered characters overwrite

Answer (score 0):

BaseFont micrBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/MicrEncoding-ZEDJ.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(fieldName, "textfont", micrBaseFont, null);